# Django middleware for adding relnofollow for all external links

Tags: python, django, nofollow

I'm trying to close all external urls with rel="nofollow" parametr:

I write this simple middleware:

```
import re

NOFOLLOW_RE = re.compile(u'<a (?![^>]*rel=["\']nofollow[\'"])'\
                         u'(?![^>]*href=["\']mysite\.com[\'"])',
                         re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)

class NofollowLinkMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if ("text" in response['Content-Type']):

            response.content = re.sub(NOFOLLOW_RE, u'<a rel="nofollow" ', response.content.decode('UTF8') )
            return response
        else:
            return response
```

it works, but closes all links internal and external. And I don't know how more add <noindex></noindex> tag to link.

Comment: This approach is a nightmare. Don't do this!

Comment: Why? Seems it work fast/

Comment: Cause middleware processes every response body with regex adding extra cpu load. As your page content grows it will eat even more. Are you absolutely sure that your regex will process new content correctly? You should write your templates correctly and avoid of invention of a new bicycle.

Comment: God be with you if you have a "directory" style page of links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you forgot 'http://' and url path. So, you regexp should be:

```
NOFOLLOW_RE = re.compile(u'<a (?![^>]*rel=["\']nofollow[\'"])'\
                         u'(?![^>]*href=["\']http://mysite\.com(/[^\'"]*)?[\'"])',
                         re.U|re.I)
```

Then, you also need to consider hrefs starting from "/" and "#" as internal links:

```
NOFOLLOW_RE = re.compile(u'<a (?![^>]*rel=["\']nofollow[\'"])'\
                         u'(?![^>]*href=["\'](?:https?://mysite\.com(?:/[^\'"]*)|/[^\'"]*|#[^\'"]*)[\'"])',
                         re.U|re.I)
```

Also, you'll possibly wish to take in account 3rd level domain, and "https://" protocol.

For <noindex> tag you can use groups, look at [re.sub() in Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
NOFOLLOW_RE = re.compile(u'<a (?P<link>(?![^>]*rel=["\']nofollow[\'"])'\
                         u'(?![^>]*href=["\'](?:https?://mysite\.com(?:/[^\'"]*)|/[^\'"]*|#[^\'"]*)[\'"]).*?</a>)',
                         re.U|re.I)
...
response.content = NOFOLLOW_RE.sub(u'<noindex><a rel="nofollow" \g<link></noindex>', your_html)
```

This regexp is quirky. I strongly suggest you to write a test for it, with all possible combinations of <a> tags and it's attributes you can imagine. If you find some issue in this code afterwards, the test will help you not to break everything.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am very late but I am leaving answer for others. @HighCat had given right answer for all of the cases except one. Above regex will also add nofollow to the link http://example.com

So regex in this case should be =>

```
import re

NOFOLLOW_RE = re.compile(u'<a (?P<link>(?![^>]*rel=["\']nofollow[\'"])'\
                         u'(?![^>]*href=["\'](?:https?://example\.com/?(?:[^\'"]*)|/[^\'"]*|#[^\'"]*)[\'"]).*?</a>)',
                         re.U|re.I)

class NofollowLinkMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if ("text" in response['Content-Type']):

            response.content = NOFOLLOW_RE.sub(u'<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" \g<link>', response.content.decode('UTF8') )
            return response
        else:
            return response
```

<sup>It is minor change. I should comment or edit but I have not enough reputation (for comment) and editing also requires 6+ chars change.</sup>